# debian 10 x64 | How to install wine i386 support properly?

Tags: debian, wine

can someone help to solve this issue?

Little brother wants to install some proprietary stuff on my PC, and `wine` is necessary.

```
sudo apt install wine
```

is OK.

But

```
sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 4.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why I couldnt install 32bit version of [libwine library](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libwine)?

```
$ sudo apt install libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libodbc1:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can cause that problem? I had tried `winehq` official debian repos - the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install libfontconfig1:i386`

or

`sudo apt install libldap-2.4-2:i386`

And, then try again

`sudo apt install libwine:i386`

And then, try again.

`sudo apt install wine32`

I hope that it will work. 
All the best.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please elaborate on why this solves the problem in the question?

Comment: or a reference for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

After Rambling for days  I have finally found a solution. The thing is Ubuntu do not come with everything required to install "WINE". In this case it is the 32bit dependencies.That's why this error occurs no matter what you do.

All the solutions on the internet I saw based upon if you have missed some steps. But after doing the same things from different sources for thousands of time I understood there was some other problems.

So this is what I did :

First I uninstalled the entire wine dependencies, sources , libraries from my computer by using :

`sudo apt-get --purge remove wine`

This doesn't remove the wine completely, So I visited the following directories and removed the following files :

```
`cd $HOME`

`rm -r .wine`

`rm .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*`

`rm -r .local/share/applications/wine`

`rm .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*`

`rm .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm`
```

If you want you can run this command again :

`sudo apt-get --purge remove wine`

Then I ran this command to correct any broken Files

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that I searched on google for :

```
how to enable 32 bit architecture in ubuntu 20
```

I came to this site :

```
https://support.humblebundle.com/hc/en-us/articles/202759400-Installing-32-bit-libs-on-a-64-bit-Linux-system
```

It said to install this in Ubuntu 12 or less version we have to run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

And For the new versions :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

I have Ubuntu 20 So I went with the second approach.
After this as mentioned in the wine's official website I proceeded And magically installed the wine.

This is the official website if you are wondering:

```
https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
```

Hope this solution might help you in solving the problems.